# dynamic 2d char array allocation not working correctly

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, char, malloc, arrays

I am trying to make a 2d char array of dynamic size. Whenever I allocate the memory, the inner array always ends up being the same size as the outer array.

```
char **memory;
int outer = 1000;
int inner = 2;

memory = (char**)malloc(outer * sizeof(char*));
for(i = 0; i < outer; i++){
    memory[i] = (char*)malloc(inner * sizeof(char));
}
```

This results in 1000 rows of 1000 length char arrays and I can not figure out why. Can anyone help?

Comment: How did you check that each `char*` points to a block of size 1000?

Comment: In `C`, you can almost always access read the data in unallocated space. Are you sure you aren't creating an array of the correct size?

Comment: I got it. Adrian's comment made me realize how stupid I was. I was looking at the watch panel in visual studio thinking it was actually telling me the size of the inner char arrays when it was just looking at the bytes 1000 characters after each pointer. Is there a way to have it look at only 2 bytes after?

Comment: Accurately, this will result in 1001 arrays allocated, One array of one thousand pointers, and 1000 arrays, each of which being exactly two chars wide. It is *not* **a** 2D array. And for answering your watch-window question, try putting `ptr,2` as your watch expression, where `ptr` is the pointer variable being examined.

Comment: What do you really want? This is not a 2D array that you are allocating but an emulation of such a beast through an array of pointers. Don't do that if you don't have to, modern C has multidimensional arrays built into the language for free. Other nitpick: don't cast the return of `malloc`, this can easily hide errors, and `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1`. `char (*memory)[outer] = malloc(inner*outer);` should be all you need with a C99 conforming compiler.

Comment: I know it is not a 2d array in the sense that every element(in each column) is lined up in memory. But it serves my purpose which is to have a large number of char arrays that can be accessed in constant time. This is just for an assignment for my computer architecture class that is supposed to teach us about fetch and execute cycle in assembly, so we are supposed to write an emulator for a fake architecture (y86) that will run y86 machine code. I am using this to create my main memory.

Answer (score 0):

This will result in a 2D array of char where rows = 1000 and columns = 2.